# Codename one label color change

Tags: colors, codenameone

I'm looking how can I change the label color on codename one.

I've tried this one but it didn't work at all:

`Labelname.getSelectedStyle().setFgColor(ColorUtil.CYAN);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Label testLabel = new Label("test");
testLabel.getAllStyles.setFgColor(0xff000);
```

Use above codes . It will change label color